# Parable of weeds - where did the enemy get seeds from?

Tags: soteriology, gospel-of-matthew, parables

In the Parable of Weeds, the enemy is narrated as sowing the seeds of weed once the farmer had sown good seeds (Mt 13:25).  But, Matthew 13:30 suggests that the tares along with their  ripe seeds would be burned, thereby leaving no scope for the weed-seed to be stored.  My question is: from where did the enemy get the seeds of tares?

Comment: This belongs at [Hermeneutics.SE], if anywhere. But I'm really not sure where this question comes from, or what an answer is supposed to resolve. Can you give more detail about the problem you're having?

Answer (score 2):

The enemy himself is the original tare.

Jesus explains this clearly in Matthew 13: 37-40.

> He that soweth the good seed is the Son of Man. The field is the world; the good seed are the children of the kingdom; **but the tares are the children of the wicked one;**
>
> The enemy that sowed them is the devil; the harvest is the end of the world; and the reapers are the angels.
>
> As therefore the tares are gathered and burned in fire; so shall it be in the end of this world.